# Issue copying string pointers contained in structs

Tags: c, string, parsing, pointers, struct

So i have this struct which im using as a tree for a parser.

```
struct Expr{
    struct Expr* a;
    char* value;
    struct Expr* b;
};
```

I initialize it with malloc like this.

```
Expr* initExp(){
    Expr* ret;
    ret = (Expr*)malloc(sizeof(Expr));
    ret->a = (Expr*)malloc(sizeof(Expr));
    ret->b = (Expr*)malloc(sizeof(Expr));
    ret->value = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    ret->value = "18killstreak";
    ret->a->value = "18killstreak";
    ret->b->value = "18killstreak";
    return ret;
}
```

I have written more here in the function than i needed to in the process of debugging so far and for printing the tree.
So I am trying to copy an Expr* a-> value into a Expr* value like this.

```
strcpy(temp2->value,ret->a->value);
```

While the values are "18killstreak" and "x" respectively.
But my program crashes at this line and I have tried many other tactics at this point.

Comment: Did you define the structure with typedef? if not, you need to use "struct Expr" and not just Expr.

Comment: Yes i have typedef struct Expr Expr; at the top of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not managing memeory for your strings, so you can't just use `strcpy`.  For example, when you have:

```
ret->value = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
ret->value = "18killstreak";
```

this allocats space for a 0-length string (just a NUL), and then throws it away (the memory leaks), overwriting the allocated pointer with a pointer to a static constant string `"18Killstreak"`.  When you later try to overwrite the static constant string (with `strcpy`) you get a crash.

So to do it correctly, you need to allocate and manage memory for the strings.  The easiest way to do that is to have each `struct Expr` own the memory for the string and use `strdup`/`free` appropriately to alloc/copy/free that memory.  So your init function becomes:

```
Expr* ret;
ret = (Expr*)malloc(sizeof(Expr));
ret->a = (Expr*)malloc(sizeof(Expr));
ret->b = (Expr*)malloc(sizeof(Expr));
ret->value = strdup("18killstreak");
ret->a->value = strdup("18killstreak");
ret->b->value = strdup("18killstreak");
```

Later when you want to replace the `value` of a struct, you do:

```
free(temp2->value);
temp2->value = strdup(ret->a->value);
```

and when you want to free an `Expr`, you need to also (first) free the `value`:

```
free(exp->value);
free(exp);
```

Now one isuue with this is that `strdup` is not a standard C function -- it's a POSIX function.  So it is available on POSIX systems (such as Linux or OSX), but not on non-POSIX systems.  So you may need to define it yourself:

```
char *strdup(const char *str) {
    char *rv = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    if (rv) strcpy(rv, str);
    return rv;
}
```

Comment: yes! you need to allocate memory before the strcpy. if not, it is memory invasion

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you!